# Schedule publishing for locked item

Tags: sitecore-client

I want to know if an item is locked by someone in Sitecore, does it prevent the schedule publishing for that particular item?

Thanks,
Akshay

Answer (score 2):

No. If item is locked (even by another user) it can still be published.

If item is locked, non-admin users cannot change their fields or presentation details, but publishing is in fact copying that version of an item to the `web` database, so it doesn't modify item fields by itself.

If a locked item is published to `web` database, the `Lock` field is published as well. So if you switch to the `web` database from Sitecore Desktop, you will see the `Lock` field value being set e.g. to:

```
<r owner="sitecore\contenteditor" date="20200205T065528Z" />
```

But again, it doesn't prevent that item from being published once more, even if it's another user who executes the publish action.